# Python аудио из BytesIO конвертировать в моно и обратно в BytesIO

Tags: python, аудио

Есть стерео аудио файл, загруженный в BytesIO

Есть ли возможность сконвертировать его в моно и загрузить в другой BytesIO?

Видел конвертацию с помощью `pydub`:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("/path/to/file.wav")
sound = sound.set_channels(1)
sound.export("/output/path.wav", format="wav")
```

Но он не позволяет работать с file-like объектами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Вот так может быть?*

```
from io import BytesIO

import requests
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play


def main():
    url = 'https://static.muzlo.cc/download/32185/Eminem_-_Crazy-In-Love.mp3'

    headers = {
        'accept-encoding': 'dentity;q=1, *;q=0',
        'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'cookie': '_ym_uid=1598301264972206367; _ym_d=1598301264;\
            _ga=GA1.2.588910291.1598301264; _gid=GA1.2.540363687.1598301264;\
            _ym_isad=2; _gat_gtag_UA_120812414_1=1',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'audio',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64)\
            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36'}

    response = requests.get(url, headers, stream=True)

    print(f"Статус код запроса к серверу {response.status_code}")

    length = response.headers['Content-Length']

    content = response.content

    mp3_sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(BytesIO(content))

    print(f"Количество каналов в аудио дорожке до обработки {mp3_sound.channels}")
    mp3_sound = mp3_sound.set_channels(1)
    print(f"Количество каналов в аудио дорожке после обработки {mp3_sound.channels}")

    wav_bytes = mp3_sound.export(BytesIO(mp3_sound.raw_data), format="wav")
    wav_sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(wav_bytes)

    play(mp3_sound)

    # play(wav_sound)  # MONO


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```